# Web services support in IntelliJ IDEA running under Gentoo Linux

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jax-ws, gentoo

Does **anybody** able to use build-in web services (JAX-WS) support in IntelliJ IDEA under Linux? Most of features don't work under Gentoo (Calculate actually). Ex, when I launch command "Tools -> Web Services -> Generate Wsdl form Java code..." from menu it says: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/internal/ws/WsGen

I know wsgen is included with sun-jdk-1.6, I have also tried to install packages "jax-ws" and "jax-ws-tools" from Gentoo repository. It doesn't help.

I know the features work with IDEA under Windows XP. What's wrong with Linux? Any specific setup is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(It's being a while before I was able to return to the topic) 
The bug is now fixed in newer versions of IDEA, at least in 12.

Answer (score 1):

This class is located in the **tools.jar** that is not added to the JSDK classpath by default, try to open JSDK settings dialog, classpath tab and add **tools.jar** explicitly to the list of the JDK jars.

Comment: I have found one the file here: /etc/java-config-2/current-system-vm/lib/tools.jar. It's not under /etc/java-config-2/current-system-vm/jre/lib (used by default JSDK configuration), so it's not surprising that the file isn't included by default.

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError may be caused by some other dependency missing, so you need to check that you have the same set of jars in the classpath that worked for you on Windows XP.

Comment: I was able to see the command IDEA launches. Nothing included into classpath at all. Unfortunately, installation under Windows XP doesn't show command console at all, since no error is raised. Probably I can find the commande templaye somewhere... at least I'll try.

Comment: Nothing. Any other ideas please?

Comment: Please file an issue at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA with a sample project attached and we'll try to reproduce it on Linux. You can also try IDEA 11 EAP at http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11+EAP and see if it works better.